# Substitution regex with groupings

Tags: python, regex

Given a string like `\url{www.mywebsite.com/home/us/index.html}'`, I would like to replace the part of the URL up to the second-to-last forward slash with `www.example.com/`, so that it becomes:

```
\url{www.example.com/us/index.html}`
```

I assume that at least one forward slash exists in the URL. Now this is what I tried.

```
>>> pattern = r'(\url{).*([^/]*/[^/]*})'
>>> prefix = r'\1www.example.com/\2'
>>> re.sub(pattern, prefix, '\url{www.mywebsite.com/home/us/index.html}')
'\\url{www.example.com//index.html}'
```

I'm not sure why the `us` part is not included in the result, even though I explicitly included the `[^/]*` within the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The greedy `.*` matches everything up to the last slash.  Then your group just matches `/index.html`, with the first `[^/]*` matching nothing (because `*` can match nothing).

Include a slash after your `.*` to force the `.*` to stop before the second-to-last slash, preventing it from consuming the `us` that you want to leave for the group to capture:

```
>>> pattern = r'(\url{).*/([^/]*/[^/]*})'
>>> re.sub(pattern, prefix, '\url{www.mywebsite.com/home/us/index.html}')
'\\url{www.example.com/us/index.html}'
```

Comment: Ah right! Or alternatively, I could use a lazy version `pattern = r'(\url{).*?([^/]*/[^/]*})'`

Answer (score 1):

Also using lookhead/lookbehind:

```
import re
# match anything that has a preceding '{' up to the last two slashes:
pattern = r'(?<={).*(?=(?:[^/]*/){2})'
prefix = r'www.example.com'
print re.sub(pattern, prefix, '\url{www.mywebsite.com/home/us/index.html}')
```

**Output**

```
\url{www.example.com/us/index.html}
```

or without using regex at all:

```
l='\url{www.mywebsite.com/home/us/index.html}'.split(r"/")[-2:]
l=['\url{www.example.com', l[0], l[1]]
print "/".join(l)
```